# How do I link with clang on windows?

Tags: windows, linker, clang, x86-64, ld

Here's some assembly. using windows clang I can write `clang -c my.s` and get an object file. I can link it using

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe" n.o /ENTRY:main

(The libpath is c:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Lib/10.0.20348.0/um/x64/)

However I can not figure out how to use clang's linker to do it. I keep getting "error: my.o: unknown file type"

I'm on my linux machine and tried

```
clang my.s --target=x86_64-windows-gnu "-L/run/media/eric/win10/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Lib/10.0.20348.0/um/x64/"
```

I get a huge list of missing libs. I don't really think any are necessary. Everything I need appears to be in Kernel32.lib. I just want to link Kernel32 with my assembly. (or windows using clang only)

```
    .text
    .def     @feat.00;
    .scl    3;
    .type   0;
    .endef
    .globl  @feat.00
.set @feat.00, 0
    .intel_syntax noprefix
    .file   "my.c"
    .def     main;
    .scl    2;
    .type   32;
    .endef
    .globl  main                            # -- Begin function main
    .p2align    4, 0x90
main:                                   # @main
.seh_proc main
# %bb.0:
    sub rsp, 56
    .seh_stackalloc 56
    .seh_endprologue
    mov dword ptr [rsp + 52], 0
    mov ecx, 4294967285
    call    GetStdHandle
    mov qword ptr [rsp + 40], rax
    mov rcx, qword ptr [rsp + 40]
    lea rdx, [rip + text_0]
    mov r8d, 10
    xor eax, eax
    mov r9d, eax
    mov qword ptr [rsp + 32], 0
    call    WriteFile
    mov ecx, 12
    call    ExitProcess
    int3
    .seh_endproc
                                        # -- End function
    .section    .rdata,"dr",discard,text_0
    .globl  text_0 # @text_0
text_0:
    .asciz  "New Text!\n"

    .section    .drectve,"yn"
    .ascii  " /DEFAULTLIB:kernel32.lib"
    .addrsig
```

Comment: use WSL (Windows 10 only) and compile natively without any problems.

Comment: I found a solution but that works but I don't think I like it. It requires copying and renaming kernel32.Lib. mingw and I believe zig uses a `def` file instead which is plain text. I prefer using that if possible. I have no idea how to use a def file to link

Answer (score 0):

You do need to use mingw if you are on windows 10. Use WSL (windows subsystem for linux), install Ubuntu or other distribution (via the appstore https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config) and use "normal" GCC and other linux tools:

[image]

I use

```
piotr@PiotrLaptop02:/mnt/c/Users/Piotr$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
piotr@PiotrLaptop02:/mnt/c/Users/Piotr$
```