# Trying to compile for linux on windows ( clang / llvm / ld.ldd ) gets a function not supported error

Tags: c, linux, window, clang, ld

I'm trying to compile a linux binary from windows. I have a file called slim.c which is pasted at the bottom

On linux and Mac I can compile it using

> /usr/bin/clang -c slim.c -static -nostdlib --target=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

On linux I use

> /usr/bin/ld.lld slim.o

On mac its the same thing but different path

> /usr/local/bin/ld.lld slim.o

Both produces a linux binary I can execute. However on windows I get errors. I tried the clang that came with windows build system and then grabbed llvm's build from their github which is 13.0

```
"C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin\clang.exe" -c slim.c -static -nostdlib --target=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

"C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin\ld.lld.exe" slim.o
ld.lld: error: cannot open output file a.out: function not supported
```

It doesn't just happen when using ld.lld directly. If I try to build/link from clang I also get a "function not supported" error

Any idea what compiler option I can use or a download I can grab?

Source of slim.o

```
typedef unsigned long long int size_t;
typedef long long int ssize_t;
typedef long long int int64_t;

ssize_t my_write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t size) {
    register int64_t rax __asm__ ("rax") = 1;
    register int rdi __asm__ ("rdi") = fd;
    register const void *rsi __asm__ ("rsi") = buf;
    register size_t rdx __asm__ ("rdx") = size;
    __asm__ __volatile__ (
        "syscall"
        : "+r" (rax)
        : "r" (rdi), "r" (rsi), "r" (rdx)
        : "cc", "rcx", "r11", "memory"
    );
    return rax;
}

void my_exit(int exit_status) {
    register int64_t rax __asm__ ("rax") = 60;
    register int rdi __asm__ ("rdi") = exit_status;
    __asm__ __volatile__ (
        "syscall"
        : "+r" (rax)
        : "r" (rdi)
        : "cc", "rcx", "r11", "memory"
    );
}

int _start(){
    my_write(1, "Hello\n", 6);
    my_exit(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm also interested building for windows on linux if anyone can help with that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69581629/how-do-i-link-with-clang-on-windows

Answer (score 0):

most likely, ld.lld does
not have write permission on the local directory